# Script Object is initialized in host, null in client. Why?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've so far been debugging my code for networking on Unity2D. As of now when I try to initialize a field in a spawned object that is *not* a SyncVar, the object passed to the field displays as null according to the Log command.

```
public void InitiateManagers(GameManager game_manager, BoardManager board_manager)
{
    this.game_manager = game_manager;
    this.board_manager = board_manager;

    Debug.Log(board_manager); //prints null when client runs in editor, wheras prints "BoardManager" if the host runs on the editor

    board_manager.RegisterBuilding(this.gameObject); // error occurs here because board_manager is null in client
}
```

Can anyone explain why Unity seems to only be able to retrieve an object *once*?

Comment: what do you mean *retrieve an object*? can you elaborate? how does your code call `InitiateManagers`?

Comment: All fields are initialized with the GameManager at start as show [here](https://pastebin.com/98TYL7VZ)